# Would assigning result from a function to a variable ruin an opportunity for tail optimization?

Tags: lua, tail-recursion

Whenever I have a function to call at the end of another, I always call it on the same line as the return, like so, `return foo(x)`.

Would assigning the result to a variable botch any possibility of tail optimization? Like this,

```
function(...)
    ...
    tmp = foo(x)
    return tmp
end
```

Comment: In this case tail call optimization is impossible: you have added extra operation between calling `foo(x)` and `return` - adjusting number of values returned by `foo(x)` to one.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I see. I assumed the compiler, or in this case the interpreter would have compensated for that since I'm not doing anything fancy with the result; just assigning it.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Would this be a general conclusion for other programming languages as well, such as C and C++? Or would that be implementation dependent?

Comment: This is because of multiple return values in Lua.

Comment: @namzug No, it depends on the language implementation. While most compilers could optimize C functions to use tail calling, it is not required by the C spec (whereas Lua requires tail calling to be implemented).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://www.lua.org/pil/6.3.html: `In Lua, only a call in the format return g(...) is a tail call.`.

So in this case you are missing the tail call optimization yes.